# Correct or wrong? "They should have paid more attention on their first lecture about..."

Tags: prepositions, past-perfect

is this sentence grammatically correct? Would a native speaking person say this sentence as it is?

> They **should have paid (?)** more attention **on (?)** their first
> lecture about **the (?)** law of supply and demand.

**A little bit of context:** "They" are no longer in school, they have a job now and they lack knowledge about something important (in my case it's the law of supply and demand, just a random topic that came into my mind)

Comment: Yes, we say to pay attention to something in English. Generally, pay more attention **to something**.

Comment: "pay more attention to the law" and "on their first lecture" (I would put the place at the end because it's less important than the subject)

Answer (score 2):

Most of this is correct, but instead of *They should have paid  more attention on  their first lecture about the law of supply and demand.* it should be *They should have paid more attention **to** their first lecture about the law of supply and demand.*, since you 'pay attention to', not 'on'

Comment: Yes. You can also pay attention **during** a lecture. (That's actually the preposition I thought of first.)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct and natural, and a native speaker might say it.

If you pay attention *to* a class, it means you're focusing on the material in that class.

If you pay attention *on* a class, it means you're focusing *during* that class. It only indirectly means that you're focusing on the class material.

So it's more common to say, "*... pay attention **to** their first lecture...*".